# Access different AWS account CodeCommit repositories from one computer

Tags: git, keychain, aws-codecommit

I am in the process of migrating between two AWS accounts. I want to temporarily access codecommit repositories on both accounts from my Mac.

I have generated HTTPS Git credentials for a user on both accounts. When I initially accessed the old account, it asked for my GIT credentials which it stores in the OSX keychain. When I try to git clone a repository on the new account, it's says that the repos does not exist. Is it possible to use different credentials on one machine?

Answer (score 0):

You could have use now:
AWS GRC Git Remote Codecommit
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

Some years ago, I solved it by using one GIT connection over HTTPS and the other over SSH.